# Filter API by its Key

Tags: json, reactjs, api, axios

Heys guys have some JSON data and API trying to figure out what the API would be to filter its category, currently only have 'food and items'. here the data.

```
{
  "id": 1587428052314,
  "_id": "5e9e5599a3f3e540e9c6553c",
  "Title": "Home Cleaning Sanitiser Box",
  "Description": "This box has everything you need - right now!"
  "Phone": "021881821921",
  "Category": "food"
}
```

Here is api: `localhost:4000/api/user-listing/`

Could I filter it somehow within my `.then` of promise chain?

```
Axios.get("localhost:4000/api/user-listing")
  .then((res) => {
    // in here ?? this.setState({ listings: res.data });
  });
```

Cheers

Comment: If the API you provided returning all the data related to the user and you want to filter all the data with `"Category": "food"` you can do this by `filter` array helper easily, let me know if have trouble with it.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt.

Comment: okay im using react with axios, i understand how to get post push etc,  so when i choose food category and go to component  im guessing i just do a componentdimount() then get all the data then then filter through it with .filter and get all the 'food' category ?

Comment: Something like that. Do you always use the same filter categories, or are they dynamic?

Comment: same ones, could i do it within .then? 

Axios.get("http://localhost:4000/api/user-listing").then((res) => {
      
// in here

      this.setState({ listings: res.data });
    });
  };

Comment: Please update question instead of trying to put formatted code block in comments. But yes, if `res.data` is your JSON object you can filter the results there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this as you expected. If you expect that one endpoint should exist to retrieve all the data with `"Category": "food"` there is nothing you can do about it with frontend tools (actually there are a couple of ways but they ain't come from backend anymore).

---

### Problem illustration

So we suppose when we call `localhost:4000/api/user-listing/` we will receive an array of objects which includes multiple objects with `"Category": "food"`, then we suppose we have retrieved the following data from the above endpoint.

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "_id": "5e9e5599a3f3e540e9c6553c-1",
    "Title": "coke",
    "Description": "This box has everything you need - right now!",
    "Phone": "021881821921",
    "Category": "drink"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "_id": "5e9e5599a3f3e540e9c6553c-2",
    "Title": "salmon",
    "Description": "This box has everything you need - right now!",
    "Phone": "021881821921",
    "Category": "food"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "_id": "5e9e5599a3f3e540e9c6553c-3",
    "Title": "soda",
    "Description": "This box has everything you need - right now!",
    "Phone": "021881821921",
    "Category": "drink"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "_id": "5e9e5599a3f3e540e9c6553c-4",
    "Title": "rice",
    "Description": "This box has everything you need - right now!",
    "Phone": "021881821921",
    "Category": "food"
  }
]
```

**NOTE:** I just made this example array of data for more illustration. You should replace it with your `res.data` in your code.

### Filtering data

To get all the data with `"Category": "food"` we can simply do the following:

```js
const arrayOfData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "_id": "5e9e5599a3f3e540e9c6553c-1",
    "Title": "coke",
    "Description": "This box has everything you need - right now!",
    "Phone": "021881821921",
    "Category": "drink"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "_id": "5e9e5599a3f3e540e9c6553c-2",
    "Title": "salmon",
    "Description": "This box has everything you need - right now!",
    "Phone": "021881821921",
    "Category": "food"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "_id": "5e9e5599a3f3e540e9c6553c-3",
    "Title": "soda",
    "Description": "This box has everything you need - right now!",
    "Phone": "021881821921",
    "Category": "drink"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "_id": "5e9e5599a3f3e540e9c6553c-4",
    "Title": "rice",
    "Description": "This box has everything you need - right now!",
    "Phone": "021881821921",
    "Category": "food"
  }
]

const newArray = arrayOfData.filter(data => data.Category === "food")

console.log(newArray)
```

**UPDATE**

So as you update the question if you want to deal with your data in `.then` it will be something like this:

```
Axios.get("localhost:4000/api/user-listing")
  .then((res) => {
    this.setState({
      listing: res.data.filter(data => data.Category === "food")
    })
  });
```

Comment: ok looking at it now I think I have to do .filter within the map?

Comment: @NateDavid-Peter `filter` itself will return an array of matched data, so there is no need to use `map` inside the `filter` or vice versa.

Comment: yup perfect! now when I console.table(this.state.listings) I get food items,  worked perfectly within the promise, thankyou

Comment: @NateDavid-Peter If it works for you please mark it as the answer to help other peeps in the community find their answer when they face the same issue. :-)

Comment: yes if you want to update it the answer was the final update you sent, cheers